# Subtract numbers from the previous data values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the situation guys: Everyday, we input some subscribers we have on that current date. I want to know how many John and Clai gained or lost everyday, based on their yesterday values. Here's an example:

[image]

I want to know how many subscribers John and Clai gained or lost on 08/29/2018 based on their numbers from yesterday (08/28/2018) and today(08/29/2018). The result will be printed on the last row.

I'm currently building a code for that, but it takes time. Here's the code I built.

```
function main() {
  var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B1:F4');
  var incolNum = r.getValues();
  var lastRow = r.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = r.getLastColumn();
  var igEmpty = incolNum.filter(String);

  for (var x = 1; x < incolNum.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 1; y < incolNum.length; y++) {
      if ((a.getRange(y, x).getValue() !== "")) {
        var add1 = a.getRange(y, x).getValues();
        y = y + 1;
        Logger.log(add1);
      }
    }
    x = x + 1;
   }
  }
```

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! It's unclear what your question is. Currently, your post reads more like "do this thing for me", which StackOverflow is not about. Please provide a specific question for people to help you with.

Comment: Hi vijoc, I'm sorry, I need help with building my code, the result I get on my Logger.log is not the same as the result I want. I'm looking for suggestions and help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code is slow because you double-access `getValue` within a loop. You also double-increment your iteration indices. My thought: you can solve this task using only spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Okay, what output do you want in the result cell, say, the result cell of column 08/29/2018, for your example ? 
Should I write Clai's number, or John's number ? Or write both of them, separated with a "-" or something ?

Comment: Another problem lies in your code. incolNum is the value of "B1:F4" stored as an array of array. In your example, it will be stored as [[B1,C1,D1,E1,F1].[B2,C2,D2,E2,F2],[.........]], and its length will be that of the number of array stored in it, which in this case, is 4, and is convenience right in your example to try to loop through 4 columns. But it is bound to fail later when the number of column increases.